# Specifying the location of a managed assembly used by a mixed-mode dll

Tags: .net, c++-cli, .net-assembly, mixed-mode

I'm writing a plugin for a third-party application.  The application's plugin architecture uses C++.  We have a C# library that we'd like to leverage, and so I've written a mixed-mode wrapper.  In the directory structure of the application, the executable resides in its folder in Program Files, and its plugins are intended to reside in a subfolder.

The mixed-mode wrapper can find our .net library dll only if 1) the .net dll is in the same directory as the .exe, or, 2) we put an application .config file in the same directory as the .exe, or, 3) we put the .net dll in the GAC.  We don't want to put the .net dll in the GAC since it will be only used by this plugin.

How can I get our mixed-mode wrapper to find our .net dll AND keep all our files in the plugins subdirectory, please?

This is with .net 4.0.

Comment: These are standard CLR search rules, the GAC was intended to solve problems like this.  It doesn't give a hoot that only one app ever uses the DLL.  You can tinker with the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event.

Comment: You already answered your own question (option 2): A program.exe.config file with a [probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb(v=vs.110).aspx) path element to specify the subdirectory. Hans gives the other way.